# DNN web.config loginUrl

Tags: .net, dotnetnuke

I'm running DNN Version 9 and for some reason pages are being redirected to the root and not to the loginUrl specified in the web.config file. This is causing an endless redirect loop. (i.e. my root www.example.com has view permissions for registered users only - this should redirect to www.example.com/Login if not authenticated)

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't typically configure the LOGIN url in the web.config file for DNN. You might look at your LOGIN page setting in the database.

You can try running this query to check how the login page is configured currently

```
select logintabid, * from portallocalization
```

You can remove the setting by running this QUERY on your database.

```
update portallocalization
set logintabid = null

where portalid=0 --assuming your portalid is 0
```

That will typically address login page/settings that have gone awry.